# How to pass array element one by one in text box in php

Tags: php

i am Reading the file contents and passed it in explod function("=",$string) ,it gives me two array parts[0].parts[1] seprated by = .parts[1] array displays all the values of the variable .now how can i use these values one by one to pass in the text box .The variable value comes in this way (value1
                         value2
                         value3
                         value4...)

my code also throws the **undefined offset :1** notice when i prints the parts[1]arrray

Comment: please give us some code

Answer (score 0):

if you have array values iterate over the array like

```
<?
foreach($array1 as $arr)
{
?>
<input type=test value= />
<?
}
?>
```